# Replace automatically := by \coloneqq

Tags: mathtools

Is there a way to replace automatically `:=` by the command `\coloneqq` ?

I would like to still be able to type `:=` in the `.tex` files but that it compiles the symbol `\coloneqq` instead.

In a way, I'm asking if it's possible to do something like `\newcommand{:=}{\coloneqq}`

Thanks

PS: if possible, I'm looking for a solution that is compatible with `\usepackage[french]{babel}`.

Comment: That's a problem for you editor, not for LaTeX.

Comment: There is an option for the centered colon in mathtools

Comment: @Bernard No: I'm asking if there could be something like `\def{:=}{\coloneqq}`.

Comment: I think semantic might be able to do this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't try this with `babel-french`, when using `pdflatex`. It should work as is if you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathchardef\ordinarycolon=\mathcode`:
  \mathcode`:="8000
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\coloncheck}{\@ifnextchar={\coloneqq\@gobble}{\ordinarycolon}}
\makeatother
\begingroup\lccode`~=`: \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\coloncheck

\begin{document}

$a := b$ $a \ordinarycolon= b$ $a:b$

\end{document}
```

Redefining `\ordinarycolon` is necessary.

[image]

For `babel-french`, under `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathchardef\ordinarycolon=\mathcode`:
  \mathcode`:="8000
}
\makeatletter
\declare@shorthand{french}{:}{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\coloncheck
  \else
    \ifFB@spacing
      \ifhmode
        \ifdim\lastskip>1sp
          \unskip\penalty\@M\FBcolonspace
        \else
          \FDP@colonspace
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \string:%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\coloncheck}{\@ifnextchar={\coloneqq\@gobble}{\ordinarycolon}}
\makeatother
\begingroup\lccode`~=`: \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\coloncheck


\begin{document}

Un example: et voilà.

$a := b$ $a \ordinarycolon= b$ $a:b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm using `\usepackage[french]{babel}`.

Comment: out of curiosity: what exactly breaks with French and not other languages?

Comment: @WillieWong With `babel-french` the colon is already active and some more somersaults are necessary.

Comment: @Colas Well, I suspected it. I added a workaround. But the simplest thing is to never use `\coloneqq`. I've been doing mathematics for several years and I never felt any need for it.

Comment: @egreg I also don't feel any need for `\coloneq` but I think that it is because my eyes are used to the `:=`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please note that `babel-french` makes the colon (and ; ! ?) active /only/ with pdflatex. Using a `"modern" engine (LuaTeX or XeTeX) is a good way to avoid all problems caused by active characters.

Comment: @DanielFlipo Yes, probably I should have added that.

Comment: `\coloncheck` should definitely be `\protected`. Otherwise you're going to have a bad time when typing `:` in an `\edef` context.

Comment: @HenriMenke No, why? Assuming `:` is not active (so no `babel-french`), `\coloncheck` would never be seen in an `\edef`, because math active characters are macro-like and expanded only when it's time to process them in a math list and `\edef` would just see a regular catcode 12 character. With `babel-french` it would fail anyway…

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `tokcycle` solution that will work with or without `[french]{babel}` loaded.  If not loaded, it intercepts the normal `:` in the Character directive.  If loaded, it must intercept it in the Macro directive.

Just surround the desired test area with `\subcoloneqq...\endsubcoloneqq`.  That can start right after `\begin{document}` and end right before `\end{document}`.

See **SUPPLEMENT** for FUTURE improvement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle,mathtools}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\def\coltype{}
\newcommand\notcoleq{\ifcolon\addcytoks[1]{\coltype}\fi\colreset}
\newcommand\colreset{\colonfalse\def\coltype{}}
\newif\ifcolon
\stripgroupingtrue
\tokcycleenvironment\subcoloneqq
%%% CHARACTER DIRECTIVE
{%
\tctestifx{=##1}
  {\tctestifcon{\ifcolon}
    {\addcytoks{\coloneqq}\colreset}
    {\notcoleq\addcytoks{##1}}%
  }
  {\tctestifx{:##1}
    {\colontrue\def\coltype{##1}}
    {\notcoleq\addcytoks{##1}}%
  }%
}
%%% GROUP DIRECTIVE
{\notcoleq\groupedcytoks{\processtoks{##1}\notcoleq}}
%%% MACRO DIRECTIVE
{\tctestifcon{\if\detokenize{:}\detokenize{##1}}
  {\colontrue\def\coltype{##1}}
  {\notcoleq\addcytoks{##1}}}
%%% SPACE DIRECTIVE
{\notcoleq\addcytoks{##1}}
%%%
\begin{document}
\subcoloneqq
Un example: et voilà.

$a := b$ $a \ordinarycolon= b$ $a:b$
\endsubcoloneqq
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

I have recently began a `tokcycle` package improvement cycle to add look-ahead features to the token cycle.  In the above "standard" approach, only one token is handled in the input stream at a time.  Therefore, to look for a multi-byte sequence, I have to set flags and macros, so that one directive can communicate with another.

EDIT: `tokcycle[2021-05-27]` has been released which incorporates code to peek ahead at the input stream.  Thus, `\makeatletter` code has been excised from this supplement.  As you can see, the directives of the `\subcoloneqq` environment become greatly simplified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle,mathtools}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\newcommand\coleqchek[1]{\tcpeek\z
  \ifx=\z\tcpop\z\addcytoks{\coloneqq}\else\addcytoks{#1}\fi}
\tokcycleenvironment\subcoloneqq
%%% CHARACTER DIRECTIVE
{\tctestifx{:##1}{\coleqchek{##1}}{\addcytoks{##1}}}
%%% GROUP DIRECTIVE
{\processtoks{##1}}
%%% MACRO DIRECTIVE
{\tctestifcon{\if\detokenize{:}\detokenize{##1}}
  {\coleqchek{##1}}{\addcytoks{##1}}}
%%% SPACE DIRECTIVE
{\addcytoks{##1}}
%%%
\begin{document}
\subcoloneqq
Un example: et voilà.

$a := b$ $a \ordinarycolon= b$ $a:b$
\endsubcoloneqq
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Emacs with AUCTeX you can use this ELisp:

```lisp
(defun user/insert-coloneqq ()
 (interactive)
 (when (eq (char-before) ?:)
  (delete-char -1)
  (insert "\\coloneqq")))
(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "=") 'user/insert-coloneqq)
```